# Get list of a tags elements from within div using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have the following div:

```
<div class="divClass">Language:
    <a href="http://www.some-site.com/something/something2/">EN</a>
    <a href="http://de.some-site.com/something/something2/">DE</a>
    <a href="http://es.some-site.com/something/something2/">ES</a>
    <a href="http://fr.some-site.com/something/something2/">FR</a>
    <a href="http://it.some-site.com/something/something2/">IT</a>
    <a href="http://nl.some-site.com/something/something2/">NL</a>
    <a href="http://pt.some-site.com/something/something2/">PT</a>
    <a href="http://ru.some-site.com/something/something2/">RU</a>
    <a href="http://gr.some-site.com/something/something2/">GR</a>
    <a href="http://cn.some-site.com/something/something2/">CN</a>
    <a href="http://pl.some-site.com/something/something2/">PL</a>
    <a href="http://se.some-site.com/something/something2/">SE</a>
</div>
```

And using this regex pattern:

```
/<div class="divClass"><a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/div>/i
```

To use in the following expression:

```
$out=preg_replace('/<div class="divClass"><a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/div>/i',replace_link(substr('$1', strpos('$1','com/')+1),'$2'),$out);
```

My preg_replace returns NULL. Basically I want to get the link from within the A tag and it's value and replace the links and values with what I get from my `replace_link` function.

Any ideea how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression and not an HTML parser? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I suggest to use an HTML parser and work with DOM elements and their attributes instead of using a regular expression for the whole content.

Comment: I don`t know how to proper use a html parser in my specific scenario. I would favour DOMDocument. Any ideea how to do this with DOMDocument?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not good: it matches only one `<a href=...> </a>`, and you provide many.

You have to use something like:

```
/<div class="divClass">\(<a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>\)+<\/div>/i
```

(not sure of the non-capturing syntax in php)

And you must also deal with spaces (space char, tab, end of line) in your input.
If you're sure of your input, you can use something like:

```
/<div class="divClass">[^<]*(<a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>[^<]*)+[^<]*<\/div>/i
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use [DomDocument](http://php.net/DomDocument): http://codepad.org/RxZ7URMB

```
// Create new DomDocument
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// Get all <a>
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    echo $a->getAttribute('href') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you want to take it a step further and do your replacing: http://codepad.org/diqRQhiZ

```
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    $a->setAttribute('href', replace_link($a->getAttribute('href')));
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```